# Flutter CheckBox not saving the checked items in the empty list/set

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement checkboxes in my app so that when I tap on an item in the given list, it gets `saved` in another list/set(I'm using a `Set`). But for some reason when I tap on any of them all the items get checked. **I want the app to save all the items in the list that are 'checked' to go in a empty list.** 
Any help is really appreciated

You guys can check all the code [here](https://github.com/theyashjha/aioapp).
And the code where I need help:

```
class FavoriteList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavoriteListState createState() => _FavoriteListState();
}

class _FavoriteListState extends State<FavoriteList> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  final Set _saved = Set();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 53,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
            checkColor: Colors.indigo,
            value: isChecked,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                isChecked = val;
                if(val == true){
                  _saved.add(context);
                } else{
                  _saved.remove(context);
                }
              });
            },
            title: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
                SizedBox(width: 10,),
                Text(nameOfSite[index]),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the piece of code that have the issue here? It is more easy to help you if you just provide the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made few changes and now your code is working.

Changes that I made:

1. remove `isChecked` usage from your code, you don't need it as you have the `Set` that contains the data of checked item.
2. Don't save context in `Set` save `index` instead.
3. give value as `_saved.contains(index)` it will set checkbox checked if index is in `Set` and it will set it unchecked if the index is not present in the Set.

Following is the working code.

---

```
class FavoriteList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavoriteListState createState() => _FavoriteListState();
}

class _FavoriteListState extends State<FavoriteList> {
  // bool isChecked = false; // changed 

  final Set _saved = Set();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 53,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
            checkColor: Colors.indigo,
            // value: _saved.contains(context), // changed 
            value: _saved.contains(index),
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                // isChecked = val;           // changed 
                // if(val == true){           // changed 
                //   _saved.add(context);     // changed 
                // } else{                    // changed 
                //   _saved.remove(context);  // changed 
                // }                          // changed 
                if(val == true){
                  _saved.add(index);
                } else{
                  _saved.remove(index);
                }
              });
            },
            title: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
                SizedBox(width: 10,),
                Text(nameOfSite[index]),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Object class to store the state of the checked box for each item.

**An example:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavoriteListState createState() => _FavoriteListState();
}

class _FavoriteListState extends State<Demo> {
  final List<ObjectClass> demoData = List.generate(53, (i) {
    return ObjectClass(
        checked: false,
        name: "Name " + i.toString(),
        image:
            "http://cdn.sci-news.com/images/2017/11/image_5475-V1247-Orionis.jpg");
  });

  Set _saved = Set();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: demoData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
            checkColor: Colors.indigo,
            value: demoData[index].checked,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {

                if (val == true) {
                  _saved.add(demoData[index]);
                } else {
                  _saved.remove(demoData[index]);
                }

                 demoData[index].checked = val; // you can also iterate through this demoData list and check for the checked items to find all saved items

              });
            },
            title: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset("${demoData[index].image}"),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text("${demoData[index].name}")
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ObjectClass {
  bool checked;
  String name;
  String image;

  ObjectClass({this.checked, this.name, this.image});
}
```